# Show S0-Ticks with Highcharts

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, highcharts

I have an Power Meter with an S0 Output with 1000/Impulses per kWh

The Impulses are logged into a Mysql Database as Timestamps.
e.g. http://www.directupload.net/file/d/3802/ggblgccg_png.htm

How can i show the Impulses as a line graph with Highcharts?

Answer (score 1):

You need to prepare script in any language like php or something which will communicate tiwh your database, get data and return as i.e json. Then load it in javascript.

More information about working with data, you can find [here](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/preprocessing-data-from-a-database)